# to read a gcp file through gdal

Tags: coordinate-system, hdf

i have an hdf file with x,y (pixel/line) datasets as viewed in HDFView. When i convert it to tif file this dataset does not appear. How should i make gdal read the georeferencing dataset in order for me to project it properly?
these are the subdatasets:

[image]

these are the datasets as shown by HDFView.

[image]

Comment: What command line are you using to convert HDF to GeoTIFF?

Comment: gdal_translate -sds infile outfile....

Comment: A you sure your command right? You provide command partially. As wrote in  documentation "You may use gdal_translate for reading image bands from this dataset. Note that you should provide exactly the contents of the line marked SUBDATASET_n_NAME to GDAL, including the HDF5: prefix." http://gdal.org/frmt_hdf5.html

Comment: Also check if gdal report GCP's  `gdalinfo HDF5:"3DIMG_18APR2017_0000_l1C_ASIA_MER.h5"://IMG_MIR`

Comment: i did check that gdalinfo command for separate datasets and no it does'nt show the gcp information...i also tried gdalwarp to try and project it with -geoloc but it says there is no affine transformation and there are no gcps..so i want to know how to make gcps readable by gdal.

Comment: The root of the problem is that GDAL don't recognise GCP in your file. May be this is a bug of GDAL. The solution is to add GCP manually via gdal_translate -gcp option. Also worth writing to gdal dev mailing list and provide your files or links to download them and reproduce the bug.

Comment: ohk will try adding them manually...also in the data product information they have said that grid mapping is specified by creating projection information dataset and defining the grid mapping as its attributes...does it mean that i have to create a dataset...will that help in reading the gcp file??  Thank u..